# Live change() for ajax generated input type file in Internetexplorer < 9.0

Tags: jquery

I am trying to to trigger a change event in a input type file Box.
This Box is generated by ajax, each time a file was uploaded. This is my Function:

```
jQuery("#file1").live('change', function(){
    jQuery('.pic_upload').fadeIn(); 
});
```

This works in all browsers including Ie 9.0. In IE < 9.0 the change event is not getting triggered properly. So I have this function:

```
jQuery("#file1").bind((jQuery.browser.msie && jQuery.browser.version < 9) ? 'propertychange' : 'change',
                               function(){ 
                                   jQuery('.pic_upload').show();
                     });
```

This works good, in IE but only for the first inout type file tag. If, after the first upload is completed, this input field get hidden and a new one shows up. That's the reason, why I need the live() instead of bind().

The problem: I can not use live(), because it does not work in IE. I also can not use bind(), because this works only for the non ajax generated upload boxes.

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea would be to wrap the `.bind()` in a function and call the function after your ajax call completes.